# How to get response from url in phonegap using javascript,Jquery

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

I struck with this problem since 2 days, I need to get data from below url using javascript.

http://www.apexweb.co.in/Apex_Quote/Download_Data.asp?un=9393910169

I parsed the static data, but i need to parse data from the url. Help me

```
var employees = [{"ContactName":"AksharmaDelhi","ContactNumber":"9313146690","MainCategory":"NONLOCAL","SubCategory":"LIG"},
{"ContactName":"AbhijeetPune","ContactNumber":"9271263359","MainCategory":"NONLOCAL","SubCategory":"LIG"},
{"ContactName":"Abhinandan","ContactNumber":"9954534007","MainCategory":"NONLOCAL","SubCategory":"LIG"},
{"ContactName":"Abhishek","ContactNumber":"9302172932","MainCategory":"NONLOCAL","SubCategory":"LIG"},
{"ContactName":"AbhishekPuri","ContactNumber":"9303928233","MainCategory":"NONLOCAL","SubCategory":"LIG"},
{"ContactName":"AbhishekZhakkas","ContactNumber":"9863027167","MainCategory":"NONLOCAL","SubCategory":"MIG"},
{"ContactName":"Abin","ContactNumber":"8891886340","MainCategory":"NONLOCAL","SubCategory":"MIG"},
{"ContactName":"AccountantSrinivas","ContactNumber":"9949861074","MainCategory":"LOCAL","SubCategory":"MIG"},];

alert(employees.length);   //get length 

for(var i = 0;i<employees.length;i++){

alert(employees[i].ContactName + employees[i].ContactNumber + employees[i].MainCategory + employees[i].SubCategory);

}
</script>
```

Comment: Do you want to parse this data in android? or JavaScript?

Comment: using javascript, i done it in android earlier

Comment: Have you tried [`$.getJSON?`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways of doing that, I use [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) the following way:

```
$.ajax({
            url : "http://www.apexweb.co.in/Apex_Quote/Download_Data.asp?un=9393910169",
            type : "get",
            dataType : 'text',
            success : function(data) {                                  
                var employees = $.parseJSON(data);
                for(var i = 0;i<employees.length;i++){
                alert(employees[i].ContactName + employees[i].ContactNumber + employees[i].MainCategory + employees[i].SubCategory);
                }                       
            },
            error : function() {
                //console.log("your call failed");
                }                                   
        });
```

The data fetched from your URL will be passed as the `data` parameter in the `success` callback. Opposed to [$.getJson](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) this gives me more control on what I get back.

In this approach I set the dataType to `text`. Meaning jquery won't try to do anything "smart" with my results. If i had set it to `json` the `data` parameter would be parsed and ready to use. You wouldn't need to parse it manually:

`var employees = $.parseJSON(data);`

Comment: I'm sure that works. What's wrong? Is it hitting the fail or the success call back? Where are you running this code? Give us some information or it's hard to help.

Comment: fail block is executing and i am running code in chrome browser

Comment: can i add any js files to program

Comment: You can't run that in Chrome. If you run it on a device you'll see it works. If you want to run it on browsers you need to do some research on jsonp!

Answer (score 0):

For cross Domain ajax, I suggest using $.getJSON()

```
$.getJSON("http://my-site-return-json.com/index.php?", function(data){
  // Load Finish
});
```

In the server-side

remember to return the callback

```
$callback = $_GET['callback'];
$arr = array("a" => "1", "b" => "2");
echo $callback."(".json_encode($arr).")";
```